# Appending/Merging in Python

Tags: python

I have the following structure:

```
[
  {
    u'123456': {'name': "Bill"}, 
    u'234567': {'name': "Dave"},
    u'345678': {'name': "Tom"}
  },
]
```

During a for loop new items are added to the list using the extend function.  Unfortunately this results in the following structure:

```
    [
      {
        u'123456': {'name': "Bill"}, 
        u'234567': {'name': "Dave"},
        u'345678': {'name': "Tom"}
      },
      {
        u'555555': {'name': "Steve"}, 
        u'666666': {'name': "Michael"},
        u'777777': {'name': "George"}
      }
    ]
```

The intended result is actually a flat structure such in the following:

```
    [
      {
        u'123456': {'name': "Bill"}, 
        u'234567': {'name': "Dave"},
        u'345678': {'name': "Tom"},
        u'555555': {'name': "Steve"}, 
        u'666666': {'name': "Michael"},
        u'777777': {'name': "George"}
      }
    ]
```

Is it possible to append to the list so that the structure gets built in a flat way.

**or**

Is it possible to flatten after the loop has finished?

Comment: Yes, both are possible, since lists and dicts are both mutable.

Comment: Why do you have this in a list and not only a dict. If you always updates the dict and it's the only element in the list, it makes no sense to put it into a list.

Comment: because i want to sort it by column after it has been built.  Is this possible just with a dict?  (im very new to python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your list is named `l` you could use `l[0].update(new_dict)`.
Example:

```
l = [{u'123456': {'name': "Bill"}}]
l[0].update({u'234567': {'name': "Dave"}})
print(l)
```

Nice formatted output is:

```
[
    {
       u'123456': {'name': 'Bill'}, 
       u'234567': {'name': 'Dave'}
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Where you currently have something like this:

```
mylist.extend(newdict)
```

You should use this:

```
mylist[0].update(newdict)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the items of both dictionaries together:

```
>>> mylist = [
  {
    u'123456': {'name': "Bill"}, 
    u'234567': {'name': "Dave"},
    u'345678': {'name': "Tom"}
  },
]
>>> mydict = {
  u'555555': {'name': "Steve"}, 
  u'666666': {'name': "Michael"},
  u'777777': {'name': "George"}
}
>>> [dict(mylist[0].items() + mydict.items())]
[{u'123456': {'name': 'Bill'}, u'555555': {'name': 'Steve'}, u'777777': {'name': 'George'}, u'666666': {'name': 'Michael'}, u'345678': {'name': 'Tom'}, u'234567': {'name': 'Dave'}}]
```

---

Although it's more clean to just do `.update()`:

```
>>> mylist[0].update(mydict)
```

Comment: That's rather a roundabout way to do it - `dict.update` does it in-place.

Comment: @RichieHindle Yes, I'm just about to add this

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.update()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update), however this will overwrite values if you'll have duplicated keys.

```
def flatten(results):
    newresult = {}
    for subdict : results:
        newresult.update(subdict)
    return [newresult]
```